# Sencha touch Overlay point to html Element

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Am using sencha touch 2.2 to build an application. Here am struck with an overlay issue. I have a celendar view in my app. When a user touch a particular date, i want to show an overlay point to that date column. Everything is done. I just want to point that overlay in to that particular date field. I can point an overlay to a sencha component but not to an html element.

[image]

eg i have a div like this one `<div id = 'testdiv'></div>`

i want to point the overlay to that div

tried this one, but no success. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

```
var overlaypanel= Ext.getCmp(‘overlaypanel’);
var comp= Ext.get('testdiv') // here i want to get the id of tapped date column
overlaypanel.showBy(comp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be correct - I have created a Sencha Fiddle demonstrating it working. Are there any errors in your app when running the code?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=sk#fiddle/sk

```
    // create a DIV
    Ext.DomHelper.append(Ext.getBody(), {
        tag: 'div',
        id: 'mydiv',
        html: 'hello',
        style: 'position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%'
    });

    // create a Panel
    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        html: 'THIS IS SOME TEXT'
    });


    // get reference to the Div
    var div = Ext.get('mydiv');

    // show the panel beside it
    panel.showBy(div);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. Its working great now. Now i can point the overlay in to tapped date. I have inserted the date field  as id for the date column, and pointing the overlay to that id. Thank you very much...